# Access Lex Chat bot from .net WebService

Tags: .net, amazon-lex

I have created a Lex Chatbot under AWS Services. Have it tested as well using Test Chat bot session.

I would like to create a Web Service on .net which can Send Request as Intent/Messages and Get response from same amazon lex chat bot.

Comment: I have created  a Fedrated service for AWS cognito and assigned policy to RunLexBots. I am having hard time finding a way to access the AWS Lex service and Send Message using AppClientID and PoolID.

Comment: Below is the Response i am getting using my code

System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[Amazon.Lex.Model.PostTextResponse,Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler+<InvokeAsync>d__1`1[Amazon.Lex.Model.PostTextResponse]]

Comment: var amazonPostRequest = new Amazon.Lex.Model.PostTextRequest();
            amazonPostRequest.BotAlias = "XX";
            amazonPostRequest.BotName = "XX";
            amazonPostRequest.UserId = "XX";
            amazonPostRequest.InputText = "book a car";

var amazonLexClient = new AmazonLexClient("AccessKey", "SecretKey", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

Task<PostTextResponse> amazonPostResponse = amazonLexClient.PostTextAsync(amazonPostRequest);
  Console.WriteLine(amazonPostResponse.ToString());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FInally i got this working using nuget package Amazon.lex model. Below is the console application for getting response from my AWS chatbot

```
        Amazon.Lex.Model.PostTextRequest amazonPostRequest = new 
        Amazon.Lex.Model.PostTextRequest();
        amazonPostRequest.BotAlias = "BookATrip_VFirst";
        amazonPostRequest.BotName = "BookATrip_VFirst";
        amazonPostRequest.UserId = "BotAccessRestAPI";
        amazonPostRequest.InputText = "book a car";


        AmazonLexClient amazonLexClient = new AmazonLexClient("AKIA25U6KRJ7AO7MODNQ", "khAIm2l1zK94zUCeG+Gg/oACIIgCAKLBkEJUAEl2", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

        Task<PostTextResponse> amazonPostResponse = amazonLexClient.PostTextAsync(amazonPostRequest);
        //Task<IAmazonLex> AmazonLexResponse = amazonLexClient.PostTextAsync(amazonPostRequest);
        while (amazonPostResponse.Status!=TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        {
            //just to wait for response
            Console.WriteLine(amazonPostResponse);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        //Console.WriteLine(amazonPostResponse.Result.ContentLength);
        //Console.WriteLine(amazonPostResponse.Result.DialogState);
        Console.WriteLine(amazonPostResponse.Result.HttpStatusCode);
        Console.WriteLine(amazonPostResponse.Result.IntentName);
        Console.WriteLine(amazonPostResponse.Result.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(amazonPostResponse.Result.MessageFormat);
        Console.WriteLine(amazonPostResponse.Result.SessionAttributes);
        Console.WriteLine(amazonPostResponse.Result.SessionId);
        Console.ReadLine();
```